# Jmeter Cassandra plugin

Tags: cassandra, jmeter

I have installed [Cassandra jmeter plugin](https://github.com/Netflix/CassJMeter).
I added sampler as cassandra put.
I have followed these instructions: https://github.com/Netflix/CassJMeter/wiki/getting_started instructions.

I've got exception as below:

```
ERROR: com.netflix.jmeter.sampler.OperationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
com.netflix.jmeter.connections.a6x.AstyanaxOperation.getComposite(AstyanaxOperation.java:194)
com.netflix.jmeter.sampler.CompositGetSampler.execute(CompositGetSampler.java:11)
com.netflix.jmeter.sampler.AbstractSampler.sample(AbstractSampler.java:205)
org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source).
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you also have a CassandraProperties config element (Thread Group -> Add -> Config Element -> CassandraProperties) defined in the test?  I get a similar stack trace if that is missing.  Make sure also that you have a SchemaProperties (Thread Group -> Add -> Config Element -> SChemaProperties) config element.

Comment: Is that an answer?